# CSS/SCSS: cartesian product of two sets of selectors

Tags: css, sass

I want to apply a CSS rule to all `<ol>` or `<ul>` that are next siblings of either a `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, or `<h4>`.

Something like this clearly doesn't work:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4 + ol,ul {
}
```

And parentheses to alter the order of evaluation seem to be not allowed in CSS.

So, I have to write something like this:

```
h1 + ol, h1 + ul, h2 + ol, h2 + ul, h3 + ol, h3 + ul, h4 + ol, h4 + ul {
}
```

This works, but is quite long. Is there any trick to achieve the same in a shorter and more scalable notation? I'm using SCSS, so it can be either pure CSS or SCSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can nest the selectors as such, using `&` to reference the parent selector in a nested context:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    & + ol, & + ul {
        // Styles go here
    }
}
```

...this will generate the combination of all headings(`h1` through `h4`) and its immediate sibling (`ul` or `ol`) in the selector format you wanted, `<heading> + <list-parent>`:

```
h1 + ol, h1 + ul, h2 + ol, h2 + ul, h3 + ol, h3 + ul, h4 + ol, h4 + ul {
    // Styles go here
}
```

This still ends up being a tad bit verbose, because you have to manually comma-delineate each child combination, i.e. you can't use `& + (ol, ul) { ... }` for example. However, this is considerably better than other alternatives.

### Update 2022: Use `:is()`

The suggestion of `:matches()` below is dated: the agreed-upon pseudo-class is now `:is()`:

```
:is(h1, h2, h3, h4) + :is(ol, ul) {
    // Styles go here
}
```

### Update 2017: Using `:matches()` in CSS 4 working draft

@IlyaStreltsyn noted in a comment below that `:matches()`<sup>[[1]](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/), [[2]](https://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/matches-any-pseudo-class/)</sup> (previously known as `:any`, available via vendor prefixes, e.g. `:-webkit-any()`) functional pseudo-class, part of the specification for CSS4, can be seen as a likely alternative solution that is way simpler:

```
:matches(h1, h2, h3, h4) + :matches(ol, ul) {
    // Styles go here
}
```

Note that the `:matches()` pseudo-class [is still not widely supported across browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-matches-pseudo) at the time of writing (October 2017).

Comment: Yep, for concise writing this is the best option right now. It will still result in the overly verbose output, but hopefully one day we'll get widely supported native CSS nesting.

Comment: @delinear True that. I believe that CSS is a rather low-level language and don't expect to see it support nesting in the near future, but that is also why we have pre-processors to help with that. Think of it like writing in C# and having to recompile every time you change something ;)

Comment: There is already the `:matches()` pseudo class in CSS Selectors level 4, which allows to write something like `:matches(h1, h2, h3, h4) + :matches(ol, ul)`. Unfortunately, this works now only in Safari.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Thanks for the heads up! :)